# Ranking with multiple columns in Dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, ranking

I have a dataframe with 3 columns

```
Alpha Bravo Charlie
20    30    40
50    10    20
40    60    10
```

I wish to create 3 new columns with rankings that produces the following that gives the highest among the 3 columns a rank of 3 to 1:

```
AlphaRank BravoRank CharlieRank
1         2         3
3         1         2
2         3         1
```

I understand there is dataframe.rank function but I only saw example for 1 column not 3

I tried this with issues:

```
for newrank in ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie']:
    ranksys = df[newrank]

    ranksystem = newrank +'Rank'
    df[ranksystem] = ranksys.rank(axis=1).astype(int)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think need [`rank`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/sdate_rangetable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.rank.html) + [`astype`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html):

```
cols = ['Alpha', 'Bravo', 'Charlie']
df[cols] = df[cols].rank().astype(int)
print (df)
   Alpha  Bravo  Charlie
0      1      2        3
1      3      1        2
2      2      3        1
```

Numpy alternative with [`numpy.argsort`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.argsort.html):

```
df[cols] = pd.DataFrame(df[cols].values.argsort(axis=0) + 1,index=df.index,columns=df.columns)
```

Comment: Hi Jezrael, I added the code I tried, because I have a number of columns but only wish to do ranking for this 3 columns, also should I use axis=1? since I am ranking horizontally?

Comment: @JNg - please check edited answer. No loops is necessary.

Comment: Hi Jezrael, great thanks for your help it works now, but I added in rank (axis=1) because I am ranking horizontally... thanks again :)